# Can't map Control-Backspace to a KeyStroke

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-events, key-bindings, backspace

I am having trouble mapping the Control-Backspace key to a KeyStroke.  The following makes no sense to me.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
public class TestControlBackspace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyStroke ks1 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE, KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        KeyStroke ks2 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE, KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        KeyStroke ks3 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE, 0);
        System.out.println(ks1);
        System.out.println(ks2);
        System.out.println(ks3);
    }
}
```

Output:

shift pressed BACK_SPACE

pressed BACK_SPACE

pressed BACK_SPACE

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably forgot to read the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke%28int,%20int%29).  Note that the modifier masks come from a different location than the key pressed.

```
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
public class TestControlBackspace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyStroke ks1 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE, InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK);
        KeyStroke ks2 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        KeyStroke ks3 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE, 0);
        System.out.println(ks1);
        System.out.println(ks2);
        System.out.println(ks3);
    }
}
```

Comment: please change link from Java1.4xxx to current Java6, nice example +1